# Auto-size of 3D CSS3 scenery - computing pixel-size of 3D DIVs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, 3d

I have created a 3d scenery (a maze) using CSS3, HTML5 and Javascript. I would like to auto-size the scenery according to the screen size, so it fits screens of different sizes.
What would be the best way to do that? Is there a way to auto-size the scenery/screen automatically?

If there is no automatic way, then I have this question:
"In front of the camera" there is a DIV of size WxH which I positioned using translate3d(X,Y,Z), with perspective P. 
How can I compute the actual size of this DIV in pixels on the screen?

BTW - I'm using Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code does the trick. 
Taking into account the size of the window on which the scene was originally designed (1920*965), this code gets the current size of the parent container and scales the Div in which the scene is contained relatively to the original 1920*965. Note - it does not attempt to perform 3D scaling of the elements inside the scene, but scales the div which contains the entire scene, while what's inside is automatically resized.

Notice also that as scaling the parent container moves the scene away from the screen center, how the code shifts the scene location to the Left and Top using negative coordinates in order to place the Div in the correct position.

```
function resizeWin() {
        wW = ourDiv.parentNode.offsetWidth;
        wH = ourDiv.parentNode.offsetHeight;
        var scaler=Math.min(wW/1920, wH/965); // original screen was designed in full HD Chrome
        var w=wW/scaler;
        var h=wH/scaler;
        var left=(w-scaler*w)/2;
        var top=(h-scaler*h)/2;


        var style = "width:"+w+"px; height:"+h+"px;"+allStyles("-webkit-transform:  translate(-"+left+"px,-"+top+"px) scale("+scaler+");");

        ourDiv.setAttribute("style", style);
        redrawScene();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

#1 - If you want to scale it, use `scale3d` to scale the entire thing up or down.  Measure the screen size and scale your div by whatever ratio you need to (e.g. if you have an 800x800 div and the screen is 1600x1200, scale by 2x)

#2 - getBoundingClientRect()

Comment: You are right about the getBoundingClientRect(). Thank you.

Regarding the auto-size - scale3d is problematic. You cannot scale the "entire thing", as scaling on all 3 coordinates at once would simply leave the scene the same size. Scaling according to the current angle will resize the scene, but makes the auto-sizing very complex.